# Best way to bind events?

Tags: jquery, performance

I want to make a simple skin switcher, the html looks as follows:

```
<ul id="switcher">
  <li class="skin selected">
    <a href="#">Skin 1</a>
    <ul class="color-variants">
      <li><label for="white"><input type="radio" name="skin" id="white" value="skin1-white" /></label></li>
      <li><label for="black"><input type="radio" name="skin" id="black" value="skin1-black" /></label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="skin no-variants">
    <label for="skin2">Skin 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="skin" id="skin2" value="skin2" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

the 1st skin gets activated by selecting one of the color-variant radio buttons, while the second is a single label with a radio button with no variants.

I need JS that:

- stops the default link action in skin with color-variants
- adds class 'selected' to li.skin and color-variant label

My code:

```
var $switcher = $('#switcher');
$switcher.delegate('.skin a','click',function() { return false; })
.delegate('.color-variants label','click',function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $switcher.find('.selected').removeClass('selected'); //remove all .selected
  $this.closest('.skin').addClass('selected'); // add .selected to .skin
  $this.parent().addClass('selected'); // add .selected to .color-variants label
})
.delegate('.novariants label','click',function() { 
  $switcher.find('.selected').removeClass('selected'); //remove all .selected
  $this.parent().addClass('selected'); // add .selected to skin
});
```

Is there any way i could improve code performance here? Is it more efficient to use:

```
$switcher.delegate('.skin a','click',function() {}).
delegate('.color-variants label','click',function() {});
```

instead of binding event listeners like:

```
$switcher.find('.skin a').bind('click',function() {})
.end().find('.color-variants label').bind('click',function() {});
```

Or should it look something like this:

```
$switcher.find('.skin').delegate('a','click',function() {})
.end().find('.color-variants').delegate('label','click',function() {});
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many `.skin a` elements you have, `.delgate()` may be more efficient (something I just found out). Check out [this test](http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-click/12) as an example.

I'd just go with the first option that avoids both `.find()` and `.end()`.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical about that test. The performance is likely largely dictate by the selector performance. Delegate uses the most trivial selector with '#nav', which jQuery optimizes for. Live/Delegates also require additional machinery to bind events to newly created dom elements which isn't apparent in a test like this. Either way, I think performance issues here are a wash and the author should focus on readability and maintainability in a case like this.

Comment: I certainly agree with your final sentence. But I was looking into the performance of delegate (or `on` as it is in jQuery 1.7) for a while yesterday and found numerous people saying it was faster if the alternative would require you to bind to a bunch of different elements. I suppose it's the binding that is faster, not the execution of the handler (which would surely be slower since it has to bubble up to the delegated element).